# What is the proper way to disconnect from an FTP server using SimpleFTP?

Tags: java, ftp

Very new to Java in particular, using the SimpleFTP library to send a file to a server.

It seems like any method call on a SimpleFTP object seems to require being inclosed in a try-catch. What is the proper way to disconnect from the server, then?

For example:

```
private void ftp()
{
    int portNumber = 21;
    SimpleFTP ftp = new SimpleFTP();

    try
    {
        ftp.connect("serverAddress", portNumber, "userName", "password");

        ftp.bin();

        ftp.cwd("dir");

        ftp.stor(new File("filePath")); 

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        ftp.disconnect();
    }

}
```

This does not compile, because of the content in `fianlly`'s body. If I move it up to the `try` block and scrap the `finally`, it'll compile... But what if my app connects to the server, then throws an exception while doing the other tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you didn't mention is that the reason you're having a problem is that `disconnect()` is also declared to throw an `IOException`.

Looking at the source for `SimpleFTP` you find:

```
public synchronized void disconnect() throws IOException {
    try {
        sendLine("QUIT");
    }
    finally {
        socket = null;
    }
}
```

All it's doing is sending the `QUIT` command to the remote FTP server then just dropping the reference to the socket in its `finally` block. If that throws .... it means the socket is already dead, but since you're disconnecting you really don't care (If I'd written that client, i'd have caught and ignored the exception for that reason and not had it throw).

In your `finally` block just wrap it in it's own try/catch block and don't do anything in the catch block. Option B is just putting it in the `try` block. The only reason it's going to throw is if the socket is already disconnected and letting the `SimpleFTP` instance fall out of scope after an exception will clean things up just as well.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the lack of information. While Java is quite similar to C#, there's a bit I'm unfamiliar with because it either doesn't exist or I just haven't encountered it. Marking yours as the answer due to the longer explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Surround the disconnect call with its' own try catch block...

```
finally
{
  if (ftp != null) {
    try {
      ftp.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```